# Multiple addons using the same name (OS X)

Tags: add-on, command-line

I got an error message in User Preferences > Addons tab

```
Multiple addons using the same name found! 
likely a problem with the script search path. 
(see console details)
```

But under OS X I don't see "Console" item on the list as Window users.
How can I found duplicated add ons on mac?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To see what Blender thinks, you need to run Blender from command line.

- Open Terminal application
- Write `cd` then hit spacebar and drag&drop your folder with Blender into Terminal window
- Enter
- In Terminal window write `./blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender`
- Enter

Then if you open Blender's "User Preferences" tab "Add-ons", Terminal displays all conflict add-ons.

(There is also patch to show these add ons directly in User Preferences window https://developer.blender.org/D791 for better future)